# Como se registran los cambios en los registros de una base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, relaciones, lógica, registro

Quiero saber como hacer seguimiento en los registros de varias tablas en mi base de datos. mi ejemplo es el siguiente:

**users:**

```
id,
name
```

**projects:**

```
id
title
desc
```

**project_members:**

```
id
user_id
project_id
```

**tasks:**

```
id
project_id
title
desc
status
```

Quiero saber que debo hacer para poder llevar seguimiento de los cambios hechos en las tablas **projects** y **tasks**, saber si se les ha cambiado un campo (title,desc,status) y quien lo ha hecho (**users**). pero no se me ocurre como debe hacerse. cual seria la mejor manera de llevar seguimiento a los cambios de los registros de una base de datos?

Comment: Esta pregunta está basada en opiniones y no expresa un problema real con un error definido y podría ser cerrada por este motivo. Dicho esto, puedes revisar tu código y cada vez que se ejecute una consulta del tipo que quieras controlar a la base de datos generas o bien otra consulta para almacenar la primera en una tabla de "historia" (history) o bien lo vuelcas en un archivo log. Quizas tambien se podria hacer con triggers en la propia base de datos, pero eso nunca lo he probado aun.

Comment: lo de la tabla **history** me interesa, pero como se veria esta tabla **history**? que campos tendria para saber que **user** hizo el cambio, que cambios hizo y en que tabla?

Comment: Pues tu mismo ya estas diciendo las columnas que necesitas saber de tu tabla history:  user, query, table... y seguranmente un campo de timestamp automático en cada nuevo registro. Pero es ya es a gusto del consumidor, por eso te digo que esta basada en opiniones.. quizas en lugar de querer guardar la query te basta con un registro del tipo "Pedro compro 5 zapatos" o "Pedro actualizó el precio del zapato Nike" en lugar de una query tipo "Update zapato where user=pedro blabla", o quizás un "se ha actualizado zapato por Pedro" o mas bien "Pedro, deja de tocar las cosas, por favor" :-P

Comment: Cierto, basta con una tabla **history** con campo id, user_id y query para llevar registro de los cambios en las tablas **projects y tasks**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opcion es crear una tabla de historia

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.historical
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('historical_id_seq'::regclass),
    action character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    remembered_type character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    remembered_id bigint NOT NULL,
    user_id integer,
    before_value json,
    created_at timestamp(0) without time zone
)
```

donde en el campo **action** guardas un string si el usuario

**"creo","edito","eliminó"**

en el campo **rembered_type** guardas el **nombre de la tabla** en donde se hizo la acción

en el campo **remebered_id** el **id de ese registro** que sufrio el cambio

en el campo **user_id** el **usuario** que hizo la modificación

y finalmente en el campo **before_value** guardas el json del **registro antes de hacer** esa acción.

Esto quiere decir que si el usuario edita una tabla primero debes consultar ese registro y guardarlo y despues haces el update

Comment: [^_^] - Esta solucion me gusta